# Sonatype Nexus: Could not transfer artifact from/to nexus, Access denied to, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden

Tags: maven, package, repository, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to set up a Nexus maven proxy-repo and to build a small open source application to see that it goes through my local nexus instance.

I have a running local instance of Nexus and I've created a maven-proxy-test remository following this [this lesson](https://help.sonatype.com/learning/repository-manager-3/first-time-installation-and-setup/lesson-2%3A-proxy-and-hosted-maven-repositories)

This is my settings.xml:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
    <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>ullink-proxy-id</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.ullink.lan</host>
      <port>9876</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.ullink.lan</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <id>ullink-proxy-id2</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxy.ullink.lan</host>
      <port>9876</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.ullink.lan</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Then I cloned [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin) jenkins plugin and tried to run

```
mvn package
```

The output is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/plugin/3.1/plugin-3.1.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jenkins-ci.plugins:parameterized-trigger:2.35.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:3.1 from/to nexus (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/): Access denied to: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/plugin/3.1/plugin-3.1.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.jenkins-ci.plugins:parameterized-trigger:2.35.3-SNAPSHOT (C:\projects\parameterized-trigger-plugin\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jenkins-ci.plugins:parameterized-trigger:2.35.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:3.1 from/to nexus (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/): Access denied to: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-proxy-test/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/plugin/3.1/plugin-3.1.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

P.S. I'm behind a corporate proxy that I configured in Nexus Administrator.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Worked by adding localhost to nonProxyHosts

```
<nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
```